# When to call [super viewDidLoad] and [super viewDIdUnload]?

Tags: objective-c, ios, viewdidload, viewdidunload

In most of my code, I have the following setup for viewDidLoad and viewDidUnload:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //do stuff...
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

    //do stuff...
}
```

However, I got to wondering... does it matter when you call viewDidLoad and viewDidUnload?  Should each one be before or after I "do stuff"?

In other words, should each one be at the start or end of the method?

Edit: To further complicate things, this is Apple's default viewDidUnload method, which "seems" to suggest `[super viewDidUnload]` be called first...

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}
```

Comment: The scheme is rather that the super constructor needs to be called first, but the super destructor as last.

Comment: It depends on if you feel your code needs to run before the `super` class performs its operations. In this situation just call it first. Before ARC `[super dealloc]` was called last because it doesn't make sense (undefined behavior) to work with the class after `super` destroys it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do call `super` last in *destructors* and first in *constructors*. `viewDidUnload` is kind of *destructor* so I would call it last. But in this case it's matter of taste.

Also, just side note - `viewDidUnload` is deprecated since iOS 6.

Comment: So it's just a matter of taste and actually doesn't matter?  I've been thinking that maybe it should be last too... BUT in Apple's default viewDidLoad method looks makes it look like it should come first...

Comment: @MikeS No. This 'constructor' needs to be called first always. The destructor depends on - if the superclass actually releases objects inside, then calling it first would invoke UB, so I suggest calling it last.

Comment: Yep, call it first in `viewDidLoad` and call it last in `viewDidUnload` and you'll be safe. But it doesn't matter if it's first or last in `viewDidUnload`.

Comment: Well I definitely understand the reasoning, but is there any documentation on this?  Again, it appears that in Apple's method [super viewDidUnload] is called first (updated my post to show Apple's default method)  Yet, common sense seems to say call it last.

Comment: Simple rule - if it's important you always find info in documentation if you must or must not call `super`. But I can't remember even one method where order is mentioned in documentation (except _constructor_ which is always first).

Comment: Hmm okay. Trying to track down a strange bug and I guess this probably has nothing to do with it then, but I did learn something anyway!

Comment: Don't overthink it ... Just stick with first / last in _constructor_ / _destructor_ and you'll be always safe.

Comment: I agree with Robert's general statement. But there are cases where calling 'super' in the middle or some other order makes sense. But this would only be done when you have a specific reason to do so. My logic generally goes like this - If my code depends on whatever is done by 'super' then I call super first. If my code must be done before 'super' then of course I call super last. There are probably many more examples of calling super first than last. The only examples of 'last' I can think of are for viewDidUnload and dealloc. And those are mostly obsolete these days.

Comment: Yep, but these cases are specific. I don't always call `super` in `init...`, because I'm checking arguments, trying to create another objects, ... and then I call `super init...` when it succeeds. BUT it's **important** what did you wrote - you must not rely on `super` unless you call `super init...`.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you have 2 class, a Parent and a Child. Child inherits from Parent. They have a method called greet which returns a string.

Here is what the parent method looks like:

Code:

```
-(NSString *)greet {
     return @"Hello";
 }
```

We want the child to learn from his parents. So we use super to say greet how Mommy would greet, but with our own little additions too.

Code: // Inherits from Parent

```
 -(NSString *)greet {
     NSString *parentGreeting = [super greet];
     return [parentGreeting stringByAppendingString:@", Mommy"]
   }
```

So now Parent greets "Hello", and the Child greets "Hello, Mommy". Later on, if we change the parent's greet to return just "Hi", then both classes will be affected and you will have "Hi" and "Hi, Mommy".

super is used to call a method as defined by a superclass. It is used to access methods that have been overriden by subclasses so that the class can wrap its own code around a method that it's parent class implements. It's very handy if you are doing any sort of inheritance at all.